# How to merge siblings child node in a XML file using XSLT into a XHTML table

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml

first time here. I searched a lot on this site and haven't found a similar example to my problem so I take a chance at posting my question.

I have the following XML document that I want to convert to XHTML using a XSLT transformation.

The XML input :

```
<Procedure Analyse="MyAnalysis1">
  <Identification Name="MetaTestA">
    <Blah Name="TestA" Result="1" /> 
    <Blah Name="TestB" Result="2" /> 
  </Identification>
  <Identification Name="MetaTestB">
    <Blah Name="TestB" Result="3" /> 
    <Blah Name="TestC" Result="4" /> 
 </Identification>
</Procedure>
```

The expected XHTML output :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>MyAnalysis1</tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>MetaTestA</td>
      <td>MetaTestB</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TestA</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TestB</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TestC</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So basically I want to have each column to be the MetaTest name and the rows to be the Blah.Name and Blah.Result for MetaTestA and MetaTestB (there could be an arbitrary number of columns)

I'm having a hard time to figure out how to merge the data from the two tables together (see TestB that has results for both tests) so they can be displayed on the same line. Same problem for TestC that should only be on 2nd column.

Thank you for your help,

Regards

Andre-Claude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a grouping problem. You need to group your test results by name. How you do this depends on whether you are using XSLT1.0 or XSLT2.0. I will show you are XSLT1.0 solution, which uses a technique called **Muenchian** grouping.

You would first define a keep to look up your test elements

```
<xsl:key name="Tests" match="Blah" use="@Name"/>
```

Then, to find the first test result in each group (which correspond to the rows in your output table), you would do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="Identification/Blah[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Tests', @Name)[1])]"/>
```

i.e Find the **Blah** element which happens to be the first element in the key for that name.

Then, for each **Blah** element, you output the results corresponding to the **Identification** elements.

Here is the full XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="Tests" match="Blah" use="@Name"/>
   <xsl:template match="Procedure">
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <td rowspan="{count(Identification) + 1}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Analyse"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td/>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="Identification" mode="header"/>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Identification/Blah[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Tests', @Name)[1])]"/>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Identification" mode="header">
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Identification" mode="test">
      <xsl:param name="Name"/>
      <td>
         <xsl:value-of select="Blah[@Name=$Name]/@Result"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Blah">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
         </td>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//Identification" mode="test">
            <xsl:with-param name="Name" select="@Name"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td rowspan="3">MyAnalysis1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td/>
         <td>MetaTestA</td>
         <td>MetaTestB</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>TestA</td>
         <td>1</td>
         <td/>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>TestB</td>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>TestC</td>
         <td/>
         <td>4</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

(In XSLT2.0, you can make use of the **xsl:for-each-group** to simplify the grouping)

Comment: Thank you very much! Did the job perfectly, I only had to change rowspan to colspan. I had read about the keys and knew they were somehow part of the solution but wasn't able to figure it out. This solution is well thought and I appreciate that you took your own time to help a complete stranger. You are what makes the internet so awesome. Thank you again !